# requestlocationupdate minTime is not working

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I am using this line in my code:

> locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 1, listener);

This works for Jellybean devices and higher. I started using a thread to start the update every 20 seconds. Does this way have any affect on the GPS since it will keep turning it on and off?

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    locationmanager.removeUpdates(listener);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    if(enapled)
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, listener);
                            }
                        }); 
                }
            }).start();
```

This app is designed to be run for a long time, and I'm worried about leaving the locationmanager running the whole time. Is it safe to remove the listener and request the location again after some time has passed? If not, is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is here...

Comment: is it safe to remove the listener and request the location again after the time pass.
since this app is designed to be running for a long time - for days.
and if their is another way ?

Comment: Why are you worried about leaving it running. Battery?

Comment: yes, battery life matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to leave it registered, it has no effect on battery if you leave it there or register it over and over. 
from my experience multiply registration to location manager are doing a lot of problems over time,
What I would do instead of you is to check every couple of minutes if the last received location was received in the last minute or so. If it didn't, register the listener again.
Btw, what do you need GPS for such a long period?
Check out the other location providers as well, they might just do the trick with a lower rate of battery usage
[Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Comment: so it will not affect the device by this code ? I need it for online tracking.

Comment: This code does violate what I wrote before, meaning it does register the listener multiple times. it is best to register it only once and monitor that you do get updates as intended.